# From command line - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

OK.  I know there are other questions like this one out there and this is not the first time that slf4j has kicked my butt.  However, I have looked at my PATH in Environment Variables and below are the two slf4j jar files included in my PATH as well as my project dependencies.

```
C:\Users\pdl\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.13\slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar
C:\Users\pdl\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.13\slf4j-simple-1.7.13.jar
```

This is what is in my pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Other applications we are running contain slf4j jar dependencies in the IDE but they are not listed in the pom file.  I am so confused about where to put what that I can't see straight.

This is what the application dependencies look like:

[image: Dependencies Screen Capture]

I can run the application from the IDE (Netbeans) but I get the following error when I try to run from command prompt.

```
C:\Users\pdl\Projects\WeatherTestDrive>java -cp WeatherApp.jar;WeatherOpenWeatherMap.jar;WeatherClient.jar com.a2i.weatherclient.Client
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at com.a2i.weatherclient.Client.<clinit>(Client.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Adding slf4j in my VM classpath and I still get the error.

```
C:\Users\pdl\Projects\WeatherTestDrive>java -cp WeatherApp.jar;WeatherOpenWeatherMap.jar;WeatherClient.jar;C:\Users\pdl\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.13\slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar;C:\Users\pdl\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.13\slf4j-simple-1.7.13.jar com.a2i.weatherclient.Client
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at com.a2i.weatherclient.Client.<clinit>(Client.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Can somebody please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

1. Should I be adding slf4j-api to my dependencies instead of slf4j-exe?  Or even something else?
2. I guess whichever one I use, I should add it to my VM classpath.
3. Does it even need to be in my pom file?

**------------------------------ EDIT ----------------------------------**

I created a simple HelloWorld app to log my name.  As soon as I added the Logger to my Hello class it was highlighted in red, so I added the slf4j-simple to my dependencies and slf4j-api came with it.  But when I opened the pom file only the slf4j-simple was added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run from the IDE, everything works well.  But when I run from command line I still get the error:

```
C:\Users\pdl\Projects\HelloWorld\target>java -cp HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\pdl\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.13\slf4j-simple-1.7.13.jar com.a2i.helloworld.Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at com.a2i.helloworld.Hello.<clinit>(Hello.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where's slf4j in your VM classpath? Try running as follows:

```
java -cp WeatherApp.jar;WeatherOpenWeatherMap.jar;WeatherClient.jar;C:\Users\pdl\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.13\slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar;C:\Users\pdl\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.13\slf4j-simple-1.7.13.jar com.a2i.weatherclient.Client
```

You're missing slf4j from your runtime. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm working with a simple HelloWorld app now.  Even adding the slf4j to the runtime, still having same issue.

Comment: **That was it!!!!**  YAY!  When I initially copied and pasted your answer I accidentally created a typo.  I just tried it again and it worked.  You're a genius!  Thank you so much.  :-)

Comment: And if you use the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html) you can run your application as `java -jar MissLucy.jar` and have it do the right thing.

Comment: this works fine by Mac Users ensure to use : instead of ;

Answer (score 2):

Maven, and thus the pom-file, are intended to build the classpath for you.
So yes, all depedencies you like to use should be in your pom file.

Regarding slf4j:
slf4j-api is a dependency that only defines an api (or interface). To make it work you also have to add an implementation. [See here](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) for explanation. So you have to add at least one more dependency. For example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Regarding slf4j-ext, i am quite sure you dont need it to simply log. Maybe you have more elaborate use cases.

To start your application from command line you have to run java with the `-cp` argument. The classpath is a list all used classes or archives containing classes. For applications with a lot of dependencies it can become quiet cumbersome to build it manually.

Use `mvn dependency:build-classpath` to let maven build this big string of jar-paths for you.

Comment: Nope!  Just logging.  I'm working with a simple HelloWorld app.  See my edits.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This concerns Java SE projects built in IntelliJ where slf4j - or any other library for that matter - is included (i.e. slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar => The API & slf4j-simple-1.7.26.jar => the API implementation)...

### Step #1:

create folder \libs in project root and place the two JARs in there [click to see project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlDA1.png)

### step #2:

Build code and make sure that the Logger is working properly inside the IDE.

### step #3:

Launch cmd and navigate using cd command inside the .\out directory up until the packages 
of the main (check 1st line of Main.java). i.e.

cd C:\Users.....\out...\testcp

### step #4

Do right click on sjf4j-api jar and copy path (path#1) &

Do right click on sjf4j-simple jar and copy path (path#2) &

Do right click on Main.class and copy path (path#3. SOS: EXCLUDE THE Main.class part).

Now, run java command with -cp flag as:

**java -cp path#1;path#2;path#3; org.me.Main**

That's it

**Note**: Eclipse users do not run into this problem since this is taken care of by using the **build path** utility.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA not IDEA